# how to use logical and in azure cli

Tags: azure

i want to get the data of my files in azure storage using cli for that i am using query command but i want size of file using its creation date how can i achieve this i have use below command

bytes=`az storage blob list \ --container-name mycontainer \ --query "[*].[properties.contentLength]" \ --output tsv | paste --serial --delimiters=+ | bc`

## Display total bytes

echo "Total bytes in container: $bytes"

but as i used * its gives me size of whole container i want specific file size or the size of file which is created today

Comment: The title of your question "how to use logical and in azure cli" is quite different from your question text. Could you provide us with more (and better) information on what you're trying to accomplish? If I understand correctly you would like to list all files in a blob container that were created today?

Comment: Yes Rick correct I want a file which is created today

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Do you still work on this problem? I didn't get any response and you also do not accept it.

Comment: Hi Charles still need to test this will update u soon

Comment: hi charles i have use it in below script.   [nikhil@demovm1 ~]$ cat nik.sh
#!/bin/bash
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=nik1991
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=riYL6tPdSMOaFQRERVTcC+8g871cmBoS+9OkMny84c6h4rTh5IFQaz6JUwWtkeLXbm/BXBsI7X4aIj/FHRtLWw==

bytes=$(az storage blob list --container-name mycontainer --account-name nik1991 --query "[?contains(@.properties.creationTime, '2021-01-25')==\`true\`].properties.contentLength" -o tsv)

# Display total bytes
echo "Total bytes in container: $bytes"
but after executing this script getting error

Comment: There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for the account key inside your storage account.
Please provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token as credentials, or use `--auth-mode login`

Comment: I have login with the command `az login`, so I don't' need to use the connect string. Or the account key. You can choose one if you need. And If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get the size of the files created today, you can use the function `contains` in JMESPath like this:

```
bytes=$(az storage blob list --container-name terraform-container --account-name charlesstore --query "[?contains(@.properties.creationTime, '2020-10-27')==\`true\`].properties.contentLength" -o tsv)
```

Change the date as you need.